# List with Dictionaries

Tags: python

So I am working with a list that is composed with dictionaries and their corresponding values. So my question is how can I make a variable called max_value for the key inventory_numbers. An if statement that can choose the max_value. I've tried this so far:

max_value = 0
    for innumber in towed_cars:

```
if "inventory_number" in cars:

   if int(cars['inventory_number']) >= int(max_value):

     max_value = int(cars['inventory_number'])

towed_cars=
[{"color":"RED",
"inventory_number":"2870803",
"make":"GMC",
"plate":"AX21690",
"state":"IL",
"style":"LL",
"tow_date":"2019-02-16T00:00:00.000",
"tow_facility_phone":"(773) 568-8495",
"towed_to_address":"10300 S. Doty"}
,
{"color":"SIL",
"inventory_number":"2870715",
"make":"CHEV",
"plate":"AV21919",
"state":"IL",
"style":"4D",
"tow_date":"2019-02-16T00:00:00.000",
"tow_facility_phone":"(773) 568-8495",
"towed_to_address":"10300 S. Doty"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a for loop to iterate over it:

```
max_value = 0

for car in cars:
     if "inventory_number" in car:
         inventory_number = int(car['inventory_number'])
         if inventory_number > max_value:
              max_value = inventory_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `generator comprehension`

```
max(int(d.get('inventory_number', 0)) for d in towed_cars)

2870803
```